# failing on rmmod

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm failing rmmod lcd_module.ko 
ERROR: Removing 'lcd_module': Device or resource busy

lssmod give me result:
lcd_module  [permanent]

how do I cancel this option? I want to load my module more than one time for testing.

thank you on advance.

*if I try to install with modprobe it wont recognize my module.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple issues here, one of which is that you should install your module and run `depmod -a` to get `modprobe` to work.

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement the `module_exit` function in your `.c` file, like this:

```
static void __exit myexit(void) {}
module_exit(myexit);
```

If you haven't already done so before loading your module with `insmod`, then the only way to remove that module is rebooting.

Comment: thank you.. I've forgot to uncomment this line for checking.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can attempt to force the kernel to remove the module with `rmmod -f lcd_module`.  Cautionary note:  This can cause system failure depending on what kind of resources your module has a hold of and what state its in when you try to force the removal.